# how to let flask redirect to the another page and the code will keep running

Tags: python, flask, google-oauth

I write a simple website to catch some data and when the user click the button
the page will jump to google oauth agree page(no matter what user type)
function google_json I am already check it works
now my problem is how to let the page jump to the url that google_json made and I can keep the code running to check the request.I know it can use redirect to jump to the url.
but it will let the function stop

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from sql import db_settings, insert_command, google_json


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/page")
def form(): 
    return render_template('page.html')

@app.route("/submit", methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    try:
        calendar = request.values['calendar']
        notify_code = request.values['notify-code']
        
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
        # google_file = google_json()
        # return redirect(url)

        wsgi_app, url, local_server, flow = google_json()
        local_server.handle_request()
        # creds = flow.run_wait(wsgi_app)
        # google_file = creds.to_json()
        # insert_command(db_settings, calendar, notify_code, google_file)
    except:
        return render_template('error.html')
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

and this is the html

```
<body>
    <div class="container-contact">
        <h3>請提供資料</h3>
        <!--第一欄位-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">

            </div>
        <!--第二欄位-->
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <form id="myForm" method="POST" action="{{url_for('submit')}}">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" id="calendar" name="calendar" placeholder="日歷的ID" type="email" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" id="notify-code" name="notify-code" placeholder="Line Notify 權杖" type="text" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                            <button class="btn " type="submit" id="submitButton">送出Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <br> -->
                </form>
            </div>
        <!--第三欄位-->
            <div class="col-sm-4">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--JS-->
    <script>

        function clear(){
            google.script.run.postMessage(calendar,notify)
            document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
        }

        document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click",clear);

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You don't and what you're asking for would be a massive security issue.

Comment: really? I have no idea. My finally target is to catch the user's calander data. but when someone want to use the warning will tell them it will catch the user's all calander data. it still dangerous? I really don't know

Comment: You're asking for code to keep running even after someone has navigated away.  I could setup a botnet or mine bitcoin without anyone's permission just because they visited my site.

Comment: oh.. I do not means to do that. I just want to know is server can keep the function to watch the user's request. Because the code local_server.handle_request() is do this thing right?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood where you want to the code to be running.  You can of course run whatever you want in flask.  What you're asking for is extremely unusual for a login flow, though.  After the redirect google oauth is going to direct back to your site and the conventional method is either to setup a callback to receive google's redirect back to you or, much less common, have them post the login code to your API.  If state needs to be managed between those it's done by by some in-memory store or database, not continuously running code (except for the flask server itself)

Comment: but i just use the google sample run_local_server() on server. and I use my phone to test when i was click the submit button the login page will open on my server computer not on my phone. So i into the run_local_server() function to get the login url and let flask redirect to this url